# Export Coordinates from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i found  [this website](http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php) and i would like to get the same code or any code to export the Coordinates .. 
Please help !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398110/google-maps-coordinates)

Comment: View page source gives you all the code you need